# How to use senlinclient with keystone session

Tags: openstack, keystone

How to use senlinclient with keystone session? Can anyone give me an example? Thanks.

```
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from senlinclient.client import Client as senlinClient


def get_senlin_client_by_session(session):
    return senlinClient(api_ver=1, session=session)


admin_auth = v3.Password(username='admin',
                         password='xxxxxx',
                         auth_url='http://vip:5000/v3',
                         project_name='admin',
                         user_domain_name='Default',
                         project_domain_name='Default'
                         )
session = session.Session(auth=admin_auth)
senlin_client = get_senlin_client_by_session(session)
print(senlin_client)
```

I tried the above example, but the following error will be reported.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/senlinclient/client.py", line 23, in Client
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/senlinclient/v1/client.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.service = self.conn.cluster
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/service_description.py", line 95, in __get__
    allow_version_hack=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/config/cloud_region.py", line 457, in get_session_client
    session=self.get_session(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/config/cloud_region.py", line 324, in get_session
    "Problem with auth parameters")
openstack.exceptions.ConfigException: Problem with auth parameters
```

Comment: It looks like the parameters aren't correct. Can you connect to other services and/or using the OpenStack CLI?

Comment: Clients of other services are available. Finally, it was found that the senclient and openstacksdk package version match problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.

openstack rocky uses python2-senlinclient-1.8.0-1.el7.noarch and python2-openstacksdk-0.17.3-1.el7.noarch. I upgraded python2-senlinclient to version 1.9.0 and the problem was solved.